# curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, curl, git-bash

I am trying to loop through an array of URLs in a bash script, and make curl GET requests for each of them.
below is the code snippet, and purpose of this request to download artifacts from nexus

```
for url in "${username[@]}"
do
  echo "$url "
  curl -u username:password -X GET "$url" -O
done
```

for some reason only the last curl request is working and downloading the artifacts. other curl requests say its curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL.
Any help would be highly appreciated, i have searched and looked in similar questions and nothing addresses this issue.

Comment: Include the output of `declare -p username` to your question.

Comment: declare -a username=([0]=$'http://example.org/repository/raw/exe/test.zip\r' [1]=$'http://example.org/repository/raw/exe/test01.zip\r' [2]="http://example.org/repository/raw/exe/test-02.zip")
@oguzismail

Comment: See, you have carriage returns (`\r`) at the end of your urls. Try `for url in "${username[@]%$'\r'}"; do ...` and it'll work